# failed to retrieve data for this request - listing SQL Servers with SMO

Tags: sql-server, winforms, .net-4.5, smo

```
 DataTable dataTable = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(false);
 comboBox1.ValueMember = "Name";
 comboBox1.DataSource = dataTable;
```

i am trying to populate a combobox control with a list of SQL Servers available on the company network with the above code but am getting the error below.

***failed to retrieve data for this request***

the code works on the development machine but fails on a client PC that has even has SQL Server 2012 Shared Management Objects installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumeration is subject to [SQL Server Browser Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) being enabled on the target(s) (by default is disabled) and is subject to on-site specific subnet UDP broadcast restrictions. In other words is *extremely* unreliable. If you want to discover SQL Server installations you should either have an administrator provide a list of servers or use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the AD database.

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server Browser Service being enabled on the client machines or on the sql servers?

Comment: Read the linked article and the answer should be clear to you.

Comment: well, i have confirmed that SQL Server Browser Service is running and then since its working on other dev machines, then SQL Server Browser Service ins't the issue here.